# Rails 3: How to use a ruby gem for date validation for non-model data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

In my rails app, I have a situation where a user enters a date of birth on a web page.
I would like to do validation of their age based on this date of birth. I would like to do the validation in the model because even though the date of birth that the user is providing is not part of the model, I do need to query the model about what is the age the user has to have for the certain item they are trying to access.

I found the **date_validator** gem but that only works on the model. 
To top it off I am not using a date field so I will have the date of birth in three pieces, 3 strings of month, day and year and then need to somehow convert that to a date and based on that date, validate if their age is greater than or equal to the age that they are supposed to have.

I am not sure if there is a gem for what I'm trying to do but I figured I'd ask before I try to code out my own validator.

Answer (score 0):

rails provides several helpers to deal with dates.

if you want to have a date input that is separated in several fields you can use the `date_select` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html

even if you cook your own soup, rails is flexible enough to merge seperate fields into one date-field:

```
Event.new("date(1i)"=>"2007", "date(2i)"=>"8", "date(3i)"=>"11").date
=> date: "2007-08-10"
```